# Apply Box Cox transformation to two columns simultaneously

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I want to apply a Box-Cox transformation to two different columns. The twist is that I'm being asked to choose the lambda that's optimal for both columns simultaneously.

`scipy.stats.boxcox` only accepts one-dimensional arrays.

How can I apply a Box-Cox transformation to two columns subject to `lambda_1` = `lambda_2`?

[Here's my data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BenjaminKay/berndt-econometrics/master/data/floppy_ver/CHAP4.DAT/COLE).

I would like to transform the columns `SPEED` and `CAP`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BenjaminKay/berndt-econometrics/master/data/floppy_ver/CHAP4.DAT/COLE',
                 sep='\t')
stats.boxcox(df[['SPEED','CAP']].values)
```

> ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional.

Comment: FYI: There are two different tables of data in your input file.  I don't think `pandas.read_csv` can handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want `boxcox` to treat the two columns as a single data set.  You could merge them into a single 1-d array, apply `boxcox`, and then restore the shape afterwards, as in the following.

Get the values as a 2-d array:

```
In [63]: data = df[['SPEED','CAP']].values
```

Pass the data to `boxcox`; use the `.ravel()` method to flatten `data` into a 1-d array before passing in the data:

```
In [64]: result1d, lam = stats.boxcox(data.ravel())

In [65]: lam
Out[65]: -0.02063317824310837
```

Reshape `result1d` back to the original 2-d shape:

```
In [66]: result = result1d.reshape(data.shape)

In [67]: result.shape
Out[67]: (91, 2)

In [68]: result[:8]
Out[68]: 
array([[-1.82384013,  7.23194418],
       [-4.09393704,  3.25939313],
       [-3.80017243,  4.39314839],
       [-3.80017243,  4.39314839],
       [-3.80017243,  4.39314839],
       [-3.80017243,  4.39314839],
       [-3.11153324,  5.01897958],
       [-3.11153324,  5.01897958]])
```